# Usage permission and citation text for figures on CrossValidated

Tags: discussion

I would like to use the figure in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123651/geometric-interpretation-of-multiple-correlation-coefficient-r-and-coefficient) showing the geometry of the correlation coefficients.  I am currently writing a book and would like to include this figure.  How do I obtain permission to use this figure and how do I then cite the figure?

Comment: I have nominated to migrate this question to [meta] but the short and obvious answer is that everything on the Stack Exchange network is explicitly licensed under the CC-BY-SA 4.0 license. You should be able to find this information on every page on the site. The link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing is in the lower right corner on the desktop version of the site.

Comment: Per triplee's comment, there is no need to obtain permission, but it would still be a nice gesture to notify the author of the post. If there is no obvious contact information, you can simply leave a comment, especially for authors who drop by regularly.

Comment: (Separate question about why the link is to Stack Overflow rather than to the current site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374161/why-does-the-license-link-take-me-to-stack-overflows-license-page)

Comment: @tripleee: actually, that is not *precisely* correct (and where better to nitpick than Meta.CV?). The precise license depends on the date on which the content was created.

Comment: Turns out it was my figure! As has already been stated the copyright on the figure is not problematic due to the CC BY-SA-3.0 licensing. Leave a comment here if you're interested - it's possible I have a better copy of the diagram lying around somewhere, potentially in vector form rather than as a PNG, which I can release under the same licence.  If I'm correct you're faculty at UBC then your institutional email address is publicly available so am happy to send it to you there. (Would have slight advantage to me to the acknowledgement in my real name rather than to a wingless insect!)

Answer (score 15):

The figure in the post was uploaded on 23 December 2014, so per the StackExchange Terms of Service it is licensed under the terms of [CC BY-SA-3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (see [licensing information in Help Centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)).  This license is a creative commons share-alike license which allows you to copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format, and remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose, including a commercial purpose.

There are some requirements in the license: you must give appropriate credit for the figure (a proper citation should accomplish this) and if you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must indicate that you made changes to it and distribute your contributions under the same license as the original figure.  (I would presume that this would only require any alteration to the figure to be licensed in this way, not your whole book; read the details of the license to be sure.)

In terms of citation, the style depends on the citation style for images you are using in your book.  Irrespective of style, your citation should include the author's name (or alias if the true name cannot be established) and the URL of the post.  The citation should make it clear that the image was posted on CrossValidated.  This will ensure that both the author and StackExchange are given appropriate credit for the image.